# Dimension of arrays do not agree

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation

I have to solve this matrix equation in MATLAB

(A + p(1)*E)* V(1) = B , **and find V(1)**

**B** dimension is *280 x 4*
**A** dimension is *280 x 280*
**E** dimension is *280 x 280*
**p** dimension is *15 x 1*

I have tried this

```
L=inv((A + p(1)*E));      
V(1) = B*L;
```

but i get this **error**

```
Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Do you know what goes wrong, or an other way to solve it?

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: B is 280 x 4 and L is a 280 x 280 and you are trying to do a matrix multiplication on them, that is what is causing the issue, the correct solution to the equation is L*B as per matrix algebra

Comment: Note that matrix multiplication is _NOT_ [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can only multiply two matrices which have same size of the inner dimension, eg:

```
Q(l x m) * P(m x n) = R(l x n)
```

So when you try to multiply

```
B(280 x 4) * L(280 x 280)
```

The error comes up.

Obviously this is because the algebra is also not ok, which should be

```
V(280 x 4) = L(280 x 280) * B(280 x 4)
```

Since the product of matrices is not commutative and the correct algebra here is

```
(A + p E) V = B
L V = B
V = L^-1 B
```

Comment: Please add the solution by pointing out that he may not use [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property)